# RegEx in Python for command parsing

Tags: python, regex

I want to figure out the correct regex expression to use in python to solve my task. The case is that I've written a bot for a famous communication program I use.

I want to extract all given information within a chat message. So I have the following pattern
$[BOT][NEEDLESS WHITESPACE(S)][COMMAND][NEEDLESS WHITESPACE(S)][OPTIONAL ARGUMENTS IN FORMAT [KEY]=[VALUE] DIVIDED BY NEEDLESS WHITESPACE(S)]

For example:

1. $mail-bot[WS]show
2. $mail-bot[WS][WS]show
3. $mail-bot[WS]show[WS]
4. $mail-bot[WS]show[WS][WS]
5. $mail-bot[WS]show[WS][WS][WS]
6. $mail-bot[WS]show[WS]a=1
7. $mail-bot[WS]show[WS][WS]a=1
8. $mail-bot[WS]show[WS][WS][WS]a=1
9. $mail-bot[WS]show[WS]a=1[WS]d=4
10. $mail-bot[WS]show[WS]ab=43[WS][WS]cd=23

Explanation:
[WS] stands for a whitespace (sorry I couldn't get them visible in the preview).

```
$mail-bot show
$mail-bot  show
$mail-bot show 
$mail-bot show  
$mail-bot show   
$mail-bot show a=1
$mail-bot show  a=1
$mail-bot show   a=1
$mail-bot show a=1 d=4
$mail-bot show ab=43  cd=23
```

Expected result (for all examples):
`bot=mail-bot`
`cmd=show`

Expected result (for 6. to 8.):
`arguments=[{'a': '1'}]`

Expected result (for 9.):
`arguments=[{'a': '1', 'd': '4'}]`

Expected result (for 10.):
`arguments=[{'ab': '43', 'cd': '23'}]`

The regex I have now is the following:
`^\$(?<bot>[A-Za-z\-_]+)(?<ws1> {0,})(?<cmd>[A-Za-z\-_]+)(?<options>(?<ws2> {1,})(?<argument>(?<ws3> {0,})(?<key>\w+)=(?<value>\w+)){0,}){0,1}$`

I tested the given regex on regex101 so far and what I am able to extract are all information except for the arguments if there are multiple of them.
So the cases 1. to 8. are working with the given regex, but 9. and 10. don't.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Best regards,
mr_5p4rk_

Comment: Pls paste the text to scan

Comment: Python's standard `re` module can match repeated groups (like your key and value), but can't usefully capture them because each subsequent match overwrites the previously captured text.  There is a newer experimental `regex` module you might want to look into, which I believe is able to deal with repeated captures (although I don't know the details).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try that out. But in the meantime I have been gone a different way where I separated the string from  the key value pairs and parsing each part separately

Comment: Your regular expression has a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regular expression matches what you seem to want:

```
^\$(?P<bot>[A-Za-z\-_]+) (?P<cmd>[A-Za-z\-_]+)(?P<options> +(?P<argument>(?P<key>[a-z]+)=(?P<value>[0-9]+)))+
```

To make it easier to extract the parameters (assuming there are two) you can use the following regular expression (and expand it to more params if needed):

```
^\$(?P<bot>[A-Za-z\-_]+) (?P<cmd>[A-Za-z\-_]+)(?P<options> +(?P<argument>(?P<key>[a-z]+)=(?P<value>[0-9]+)))(?P<options2> +(?P<argument2>(?P<key2>[a-z]+)=(?P<value2>[0-9]+)))
```

You can verify that it works [here](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5E%5C%24(%3FP%3Cbot%3E%5BA-Za-z%5C-_%5D%2B)%20(%3FP%3Ccmd%3E%5BA-Za-z%5C-_%5D%2B)(%3FP%3Coptions%3E%20%2B(%3FP%3Cargument%3E(%3FP%3Ckey%3E%5Ba-z%5D%2B)%3D(%3FP%3Cvalue%3E%5B0-9%5D%2B)))%2B&test_string=%24mail-bot%20show%20ab%3D43%20cd%3D23&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

The issue you had was related with invalid repeat patterns, invalid named groups, and missing whitespace here and there.

Comment: @mr_5p4rk_ : could you please review the answer and accept / upvote it if you find it useful?